# How do I set up an email template with dynamic dates or alternatively, create a macro to insert a date?

Tags: vba, date, outlook

I have a template for a report I send out every week and in four separate places (three in the body, one in the subject line) is a date that corresponds to the Monday of the prior week.  (Basically, it's a "week of" date for the week I'm reporting, which is always the previous week.)

I want to add a date to where I have the cursor.  (If I could somehow set up bookmarks in the template for where I want the date added, that would be even better.)  I've done a lot of research on inserting text and I keep running into the same two problems with the examples I've been finding:

1. I can write a macro that will open up a new message and populate various areas (subject line, body, etc.), but I can't get that macro to work on just a message that I already have open.
2. For all of the examples I've tried that actually run on the message that I already have open, I can only get it to add text to the body.  I was hoping to create something simple like how Word does:

   ```
   Selection.TypeText Text:="Hello!"
   ```

None of these approaches have worked for me.

---

***edit #1:** Of course, right after I post this, I find that one of the solutions I found to simply add text to where the cursor is now works.

```
TypeName(Application.ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then
    SendKeys Format(Now, "MMMM dd, yyyy")
    DoEvents
End If
```

If I stick with this approach, I just need to know how to set it up so that instead of today's date, it inserts the date from the prior week's Monday (I don't always run the report on the same day, so I can't just tell it to do something simple like subtract eight days from today's date).  I'd also like to know if I can tell it to insert that date into multiple places by doing something like a find/replace.

---

***edit #2:** I've also come across a decent example of a quick find/replace for the body.  The only problem with it is that it completely strips out any and all formatting, including tables, colors, etc.

```
Dim Insp As Inspector
Dim obj As Object

    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

    obj.Body = Replace(obj.Body, "xxxxxxxxxx", Format(Now - 8, "MMMM dd, yyyy"))

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing
```

(You may also notice I added a `-8` to the date format.  I figured that if I can't get it to always add the exact date I'm looking for, I can at least get it close.)

Comment: be nice to see the whole code for generating the email.   Why would you need to use sendkeys?  If you create the email from a template you should be able to reference the mailitem and use that to access the body, subject and all other fields.

Comment: I've had years of experience with Word VBA, but I'm really a beginner at Outlook, so I really can't answer your question about why I did something like using `SendKeys`, other than to say I found the example online and made tweaks to it.  As far as the code for generating the email, it's really nothing special.  I just created an email with some text, tables, and my signature, and saved it as a template.  The macro simply opens that template, so that I can manually fill in the blanks and hit Send.

Comment: Are you running this inside of outlook or in Excel, a vbscript?  I will post some sample code in just a bit if Max doesnt get to it first.

Comment: Thanks, @Sorceri, I'm running this entirely within Outlook.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured out how insert the exact date I need and I've got it simplified down to one easy macro that opens the template and changes the dates in the body and subject line to the date from the prior week's Monday.  Since this solution does everything I was originally  looking to accomplish, I figured I should create a new answer.  I'm apprehensive about deleting or editing the previous answer because someone might still find its information useful.  Without further ado, here is the code I'm now using:

```
Sub ReportProduction()
Dim StartDay_of_LastWeek As String
Dim Insp As Inspector
Dim obj As Object
Dim myTemplate As Outlook.MailItem
StartDay_of_LastWeek = Format(GetWeekStartDate(CDate(Now - 7), vbMonday), _
    "MMMM dd, yyyy")
Set myTemplate = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("Appdata") _
    & "\Microsoft\Templates\ReportProduction.oft")

    myTemplate.Display

    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

    obj.HTMLBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", StartDay_of_LastWeek)
    obj.Subject = Replace(obj.Subject, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", StartDay_of_LastWeek)

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I also needed to add the following function:

```
Function GetWeekStartDate(ByVal strDate, _
    Optional ByVal lngStartDay As Long = 2) As String
GetWeekStartDate = DateAdd("d", -Weekday(CDate(strDate), _
    lngStartDay) + 1, CDate(strDate))
End Function
```

Comment: Take a look at what I posted, you still have stuff going on that you dont need such as the inspectors.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick and simple way to replace the text in email. I think the only issue may be with calculating the date for the monday.  I will update that in a minute

```
Sub ReportProduction()
Dim myTemplate As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myTemplate = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("Appdata") & _
        "\Microsoft\Templates\ReportProduction.oft")
    myTemplate.HTMLBody = Replace(myTemplate.HTMLBody, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", Format(Now + DaysUntilMonday - 7, "MMMM dd, yyyy"))
    myTemplate.Subject = Replace(myTemplate.Subject, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", Format(Now + DaysUntilMonday - 7, "MMMM dd, yyyy"))
    myTemplate.Display
    Set myTemplate = Nothing
End Sub
```

I took the below method, as it calulates the future Monday and used it, it was code I already had.
and it is used such as Format(Now + DaysUntilMonday - 7, "MMMM dd, yyyy") so get the upcoming Monday and then subtract 7 giving you the previous Monday.  The code can be revamped to calculate the previous monday in one shot though

```
Function DaysUntilMonday() As Integer
Dim currentDay As Integer
Dim retVal As Integer
currentDay = DatePart("w", DateTime.Now)
    If currentDay = vbSunday Then 'vbSunday 1 Sunday (default)
        retVal = 1
    ElseIf currentDay = vbMonday Then 'vbMonday 2 Monday
        retVal = 7
    ElseIf currentDay = vbTuesday Then 'vbTuesday 3 Tuesday
        retVal = 6
    ElseIf currentDay = vbWednesday Then 'vbWednesday 4 Wednesday
        retVal = 5
    ElseIf currentDay = vbThursday Then 'vbThursday 5 Thursday
        retVal = 4
    ElseIf currentDay = vbFriday Then 'vbFriday 6 Friday
        retVal = 3
    ElseIf currentDay = vbSaturday Then 'vbSaturday 7 Saturday
        retVal = 2
    End If
DaysUntilMonday = retVal
End Function
```

Comment: the subject is updating, but not HTMLBody. Can i now the reason plz

Answer (score 1):

Due to being mobile I cant post ready code at the moment but I am sure you can solve this yourself with two hints:
For the formatting problem use .htmlbody instead of body
For Monday last week use datediff; starting today minus 7 days plus the werkday-number of today.

I hope this helps,
Max

Comment: If you take a look at the answer I just posted, I think I solved the first issue using a different find/replace method, so the formatting is no longer an issue.  For the date, I know what you're talking about, but I can't figure out how to write that code.  More specifically, I don't know how to get the workday number of today.

Comment: After trying your suggestion of using .htmlbody, I like this approach even better than the find/replace approach I posted below, as the code is much simpler.  Unlike the find/replace approach, this doesn't let you undo the change it makes when you run it... I first thought that was a bug, but I now realize it's a feature.  If I add that code to the end of the macro that opens my template, it quickly adds the dates without letting me undo anything, so it looks like the dates were part of the template all along.  I still don't know how to get the workday number of today, but this a great start.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the perfect answer, but I have figured out a very workable solution, so I figured I would share it in case anyone has the same issue in the future.

First of all, @Sorceri asked to see the code I used to generate the email, so here it is:

```
Sub ReportProduction()
Dim myTemplate As Outlook.MailItem
Set myTemplate = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(Environ("Appdata") & _
    "\Microsoft\Templates\ReportProduction.oft")
myTemplate.Display
End Sub
```

Like I said before, it simply launches an email template that I created in advance.

Now I use the following code to do a find/replace in the body (which I just found and tweaked to suit my needs):

```
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim myObject As Object
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim mySelection As Word.Selection
Dim strItem, strGreeting As String

Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
Set myObject = myInspector.CurrentItem

'The active inspector is displaying a mail item.
If myObject.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" And myInspector.IsWordMail = True Then
    Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem
    'Grab the body of the message using a Word Document object.
    Set myDoc = myInspector.WordEditor
    myDoc.Range.Find.ClearFormatting
    Set mySelection = myDoc.Application.Selection
    With mySelection.Find
        .Text = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        .Replacement.Text = Format(Now - 8, "MMMM dd, yyyy")
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    If mySelection.Find.Execute = True Then
        mySelection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
End If
```

I feel like some of this might be overkill, but it runs perfectly.  Because this only does a find/replace on the body, I added the following afterwards to take care of the subject line.

```
Dim Insp As Inspector
Dim obj As Object

    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

    obj.Subject = Replace(obj.Subject, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", _
        Format(Now - 8, "MMMM dd, yyyy"))

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing
```

It's not perfect and I'm sure it could be optimized somehow so that the first find/replace handles both the body and the subject line, but I'm really happy with the results.

I just wish I knew more about date formatting so that I could make it enter the Monday of the prior week instead of just counting back eight days.