# Field for next working day in outlook template file?

Tags: outlook

I was hoping to be able to create a mail template with an automatically updating field for the next working day.

As of now I have found `{ TIME \@ "d-M-yyyy" }`, which displays todays time (it updates if the template is opened on another day). But I have no clue on how to show tomorrows date, not to mention the next working day. Functions such as EXCEL's `WORKDAY` do not seem to work.

Can I create an automatically updating field in an outlook template that will always show the next (working) day?

Comment: I think thoses can be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/q/19711400/9940803

Comment: Thanks @pascalsanchez I was hoping for a method without macro's, but I will look into it.

Comment: i'm going to find way without any macro's .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i might have a solution for you. I assumed by working days you mean Mo-Fr, ignore holidays and the like.

Because copy and pasting complex field code is a royal pain I can only give you a screenshot.  But i have also attached working example in form of a word doc and an outlook template: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EYAR5GzIEw8YatGZ_wGsBXNfxf4BV8HI?usp=sharing

Unfortunately field codes don't seem to have anything to get the day of the week as a number. So in my example I have referenced english day names, you may need to adjust accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

[Screen shot of field code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GE7a.png)

Comment: Whoow thanks, this looks really promising. I'll need to take a better look, but for now many thanks. Furthermore, in terms of Stack overflow policies, the actual answer should be embedded in your post and not be a linked resource (in case the link goes down). Could you edit the post a little so the essential parts of the answer are visible here?